# Direct3D 11: only showing clear color

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

I'm making my first attempt at learning DX11, and the goal is to add the API to [my rendition](https://github.com/pdm-pcb/pdrender) of [The Cherno's Hazel Engine](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98dC-V-N3m0Go4deliWHPFwT). Along the OpenGL track, I've got Dear ImGui working and I can transform a textured quad. Huzzah.

I've got Direct3D up and running, but something is awry. My window has the appropriate clear color, but doesn't even display the FPS/resource utilization OSD from RivaTuner. It seems reasonable to me that means I'm swapping the buffers before drawing to the back buffer, but for the life of me I can't isolate the mistake. I've based what code I do have on the Microsoft [Getting Started tutorials](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Using-DeviceResources). I'll post as much meaningful code as I can without going overboard, hopefully.

There are five classes which matter here:

- `Application`: owns the window, the rendering API, and runs the main loop
- `Window`: owns the rendering context and handles the Win32 callbacks
- `RenderingContext`: holds all of the device/display/etc information, and is responsible for swapping buffers
- `RenderAPI`: clears the back buffer and receives draw calls
- `Layer`: a means by which to order drawing different elements

The main loop (in `Application`) runs through the layer stack and calls everyone's `update()` function, then calls `update()` on `Window` and repeats. The "client" is expected to push their own `Layer` subclass onto the stack as well.

It's convoluted for how simple it is, but this is design/architecture practice as much as it's about graphics or games. Anyway, all of the above works with OpenGL, but with D3D I get the aforementioned cleared-but-blank screen.

I'll start with the main loop and post the more complete setup code below.

```
void Application::run() {
    while(_running) {
        for(auto layer : _layers) {
            layer->update();
        }
        _window->update();
    }
}
```

When the client's `Layer` subclass is updated, it asks its `RenderAPI` to set the clear color and clear the back buffer. Those requests call this code:

```
void DX11RenderAPI::set_clear_color(const float color[4]) {
    _clear_color[0] = color[0];
    _clear_color[1] = color[1];
    _clear_color[2] = color[2];
    _clear_color[3] = color[3];
}

void DX11RenderAPI::clear() {
    _dc  = _context->device_context();
    _rtv = _context->render_target_view();
    _dsv = _context->depth_stencil_view();

    _dc->ClearRenderTargetView(_rtv.Get(), _clear_color);
    _dc->ClearDepthStencilView(_dsv.Get(),
                               D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL,
                               1.0f, 0);
    _dc->OMSetRenderTargets(1, _rtv.GetAddressOf(), _dsv.Get());
    _dc->RSSetViewports(1, &_context->viewport());
}
```

Then the main loop updates its associated `Window`, which results in the following:

```
void DX11Window::update() {
    MSG msg{ };
    while(::PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    _context->swap_buffers();
}
```

And finally, `Window`'s `RenderingContext` swaps the buffers:

```
void DX11Context::swap_buffers() {
    _swapchain->Present(1, 0);
    _device_context->DiscardView(_render_target_view.Get());
    if(_depth_stencil_view) {
        _device_context->DiscardView(_depth_stencil_view.Get());
    }
}
```

For completeness, here's the Win32 setup code:

```
void DX11Window::init() {
    ENGINE_INFO("Creating Win32 Window {}: {}x{}", _data._title,
                                                   _data._width,
                                                   _data._height);
    if(!DirectX::XMVerifyCPUSupport()) {
        ENGINE_CRITICAL("CPU does not support DirectXMath.");
        return;
    }

    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINITBASE_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        ENGINE_CRITICAL("CoInitializeEx() failed.");
        return;
    }

    WNDCLASSEX wcex{ };
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = window_proc;
    wcex.hIcon = ::LoadIcon(0, "IDI_ICON");
    wcex.hCursor = ::LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszClassName = _data._title.c_str();
    wcex.hIconSm = ::LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, "IDI_ICON");
    wcex.cbWndExtra = sizeof(void *);

    if(!::RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) {
        ENGINE_CRITICAL("Failed to register window class.");
        return;
    }

    RECT rc = {
        0, 0,
        static_cast<LONG>(_data._width),
        static_cast<LONG>(_data._height)
    };

    ::AdjustWindowRect(&rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    _window = ::CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        _data._title.c_str(),
        _data._title.c_str(),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        rc.right - rc.left,
        rc.bottom - rc.top,
        nullptr, nullptr, 0, this);

    if(_window == nullptr) {
        ENGINE_ERROR("CreateWindowExW failed: ",
                         get_last_error_as_string());

        ::UnregisterClass(wcex.lpszClassName, 0);
        return;
    }

    ::SetWindowLongPtr(_window, 0, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(this));

    _context = new DX11Context(_window);
    _context->init();
    set_vsync(_data._vsync);

    ::ShowWindow(_window, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

And the D3D setup code. It's pulled nearly whole cloth from the Microsoft tutorials, but I've already caught a couple errors in my transcription:

```
void DX11Context::init() {
    create_device_resources();
    create_window_dependent_resources();
}

void DX11Context::create_device_resources() {
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

    create_factory();

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> adapter;
    get_hardware_adapter(adapter.GetAddressOf());

    // Create the Direct3D 11 API device object and a corresponding context.
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;

    UINT device_flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

#ifdef DEBUG
    device_flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    if(adapter) {
        hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
            adapter.Get(),
            D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
            nullptr,
            device_flags,
            feature_level_list,
            1,
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
            device.GetAddressOf(),  // Returns the Direct3D device created.
            &_feature_level,        // Returns feature level of device created.
            context.GetAddressOf()  // Returns the device immediate context.
        );
    }

#ifndef NDEBUG
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Debug> d3d_debug;
    if(SUCCEEDED(device.As(&d3d_debug))) {
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11InfoQueue> d3d_info_queue;
        if (SUCCEEDED(d3d_debug.As(&d3d_info_queue)))
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
            d3d_info_queue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_CORRUPTION, true);
            d3d_info_queue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D11_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR, true);
#endif
            D3D11_MESSAGE_ID hide [] =
            {
                D3D11_MESSAGE_ID_SETPRIVATEDATA_CHANGINGPARAMS,
            };
            D3D11_INFO_QUEUE_FILTER filter = {};
            filter.DenyList.NumIDs = static_cast<UINT>(std::size(hide));
            filter.DenyList.pIDList = hide;
            d3d_info_queue->AddStorageFilterEntries(&filter);
        }
    }
#endif

    hr = device.As(&_device);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {
        ENGINE_CRITICAL("Failed to create DX11 device: ({}) {}",
                            hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
        return;
    }

    hr = context.As(&_device_context);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {
        ENGINE_CRITICAL("Failed to create DX11 device context: ({}) {}",
                            hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
        return;
    }

    ENGINE_INFO("Initialized DirectX 11.4 device and device context");

    hr = context.As(&_annotation);
    if(FAILED(hr)) {
        ENGINE_CRITICAL("Failed to create DX11 annotation: ({}) {}",
                        hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
        return;
    }
}

void DX11Context::create_factory() {
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;
#if defined(_DEBUG) && (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0603 /*_WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE*/)
    bool debugDXGI = false;
    {
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIInfoQueue> info_queue;
        if(SUCCEEDED(::DXGIGetDebugInterface1(0,
                        IID_PPV_ARGS(info_queue.GetAddressOf())))) {
            debugDXGI = true;

            hr = ::CreateDXGIFactory2(
                DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG,
                IID_PPV_ARGS(_factory.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf())
            );

            if(FAILED(hr)) {
                ENGINE_CRITICAL("CreateDXGIFactory2() failed: ({}) {}",
                                    hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
                return;
            }

            info_queue->
                SetBreakOnSeverity(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL,
                                   DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                   true);
            info_queue->
                SetBreakOnSeverity(DXGI_DEBUG_ALL,
                                   DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_CORRUPTION,
                                   true);

            DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_MESSAGE_ID hide[] =
            {
                80 /* IDXGISwapChain::GetContainingOutput:
                      The swapchain's adapter does not control the output on
                      which the swapchain's window resides. */,
            };

            DXGI_INFO_QUEUE_FILTER filter{ };
            filter.DenyList.NumIDs = static_cast<UINT>(std::size(hide));
            filter.DenyList.pIDList = hide;
            info_queue->AddStorageFilterEntries(DXGI_DEBUG_DXGI, &filter);
        }
    }

    if (!debugDXGI)
#endif
    {
        hr = ::CreateDXGIFactory1(
            IID_PPV_ARGS(_factory.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf())
        );

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            ENGINE_CRITICAL("CreateDXGIFactory1() failed: ({}) {}",
                                hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
            return;
        }
    }
}

void DX11Context::create_window_dependent_resources() {
    HRESULT hr;
    // Clear the previous window size specific context.
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* null_views[] = {nullptr};
    _device_context->OMSetRenderTargets(static_cast<UINT>(std::size(null_views)),
                                        null_views, nullptr);
    _render_target_view.Reset();
    _depth_stencil_view.Reset();
    _render_target.Reset();
    _depth_stencil.Reset();
    _device_context->Flush();

    // Determine the render target size in pixels.
    const UINT back_buffer_width =
        std::max<UINT>(
            static_cast<UINT>(_output_size.right - _output_size.left),
            1u
        );

    const UINT back_buffer_height =
        std::max<UINT>(
            static_cast<UINT>(_output_size.bottom - _output_size.top),
            1u
        );

    if (_swapchain) {
        // If the swap chain already exists, resize it.
        hr = _swapchain->ResizeBuffers(
            _back_buffer_count,
            back_buffer_width,
            back_buffer_height,
            _back_buffer_format,
            0u
        );

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            ENGINE_CRITICAL("Could not resize swapchain: ({}) {}",
                            hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Create a descriptor for the swap chain.
        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapchain_desc{ };
        swapchain_desc.Width = back_buffer_width;
        swapchain_desc.Height = back_buffer_height;
        swapchain_desc.Format = _back_buffer_format;
        swapchain_desc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
        swapchain_desc.BufferCount = _back_buffer_count;
        swapchain_desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        swapchain_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        swapchain_desc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
        swapchain_desc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
        swapchain_desc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE;
        swapchain_desc.Flags = 0;

        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FULLSCREEN_DESC fs_swapchain_desc{ };
        fs_swapchain_desc.Windowed = TRUE;

        // Create a SwapChain from a Win32 window.
        hr = _factory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(
            _device.Get(),
            _window,
            &swapchain_desc,
            &fs_swapchain_desc,
            nullptr, _swapchain.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()
        );

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            ENGINE_CRITICAL("Could not create swapchain for HWND: ({}) {}",
                            hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
        }

        // This class does not support exclusive full-screen mode and prevents
        // DXGI from responding to the ALT+ENTER shortcut
        hr = _factory->MakeWindowAssociation(_window, DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER);

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            ENGINE_CRITICAL("Unable to make window association: ({}) {}",
                            hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
            return;
        }
    }

    // Create a render target view of the swap chain back buffer.
    hr = _swapchain->
        GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(_render_target.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));

    if(FAILED(hr)) {
        ENGINE_CRITICAL("Could not get back buffer from swapchain: ({}) {}",
                            hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
        return;
    }

    CD3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC
        rt_view_desc(D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D, _back_buffer_format);
    hr = _device->CreateRenderTargetView(
        _render_target.Get(),
        &rt_view_desc,
        _render_target_view.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()
    );

    if(FAILED(hr)) {
        ENGINE_CRITICAL("Unable to create render target view: ({}) {}",
                            hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
        return;
    }

    if (_depth_buffer_format != DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN) {
        // Create a depth stencil view for use with 3D rendering if needed.
        CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depth_stencil_desc(
            _depth_buffer_format,
            back_buffer_width,
            back_buffer_height,
            1, // This depth stencil view has only one texture.
            1, // Use a single mipmap level.
            D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL
        );

        hr = _device->CreateTexture2D(
            &depth_stencil_desc,
            nullptr,
            _depth_stencil.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()
        );

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            ENGINE_CRITICAL("Unable to create depth stencil texture: ({}) {}",
                            hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
            return;
        }

        CD3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dsv_desc(D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D);
        hr = _device->CreateDepthStencilView(
            _depth_stencil.Get(),
            &dsv_desc,
            _depth_stencil_view.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()
        );

        if(FAILED(hr)) {
            ENGINE_CRITICAL("Failed to create depth stencil view: ({}) {}",
                            hr, DX11Window::get_last_error_as_string());
            return;
        }
    }

    // Set the 3D rendering viewport to target the entire window.
    _viewport = CD3D11_VIEWPORT(
        0.0f,
        0.0f,
        static_cast<float>(back_buffer_width),
        static_cast<float>(back_buffer_height)
    );
}

void DX11Context::get_hardware_adapter(IDXGIAdapter1 **adapter) {
    HRESULT hr;

    *adapter = nullptr;

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter4> possible_adapter;
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IDXGIFactory6> factory6;

    hr = _factory.As(&factory6);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        for(UINT adapter_index = 0;
            SUCCEEDED(factory6->EnumAdapterByGpuPreference(
                adapter_index,
                DXGI_GPU_PREFERENCE_HIGH_PERFORMANCE,
                IID_PPV_ARGS(possible_adapter.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf())));
            adapter_index++)
        {
            DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC1 desc;
            possible_adapter->GetDesc1(&desc);

            if(desc.Flags & DXGI_ADAPTER_FLAG_SOFTWARE) {
                // Don't select the Basic Render Driver adapter.
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    if(!possible_adapter) {
        ENGINE_CRITICAL("Could not locate IDXGIAdapter4");
        return;
    }

    *adapter = possible_adapter.Detach();
}
```

And finally, the client's `Layer` subclass:

```
class ExampleLayer : public Layer {
public:
    void on_event(Event &event) override {
        if(event._type == EventType::KeyPressed) {
            if(event.key() == KEY_ESCAPE) {
                CLIENT_INFO("Closing the window");
                _app->window()->trigger_close_event();
            }
        }
    }

    void update() {
        _render_api->set_clear_color(clear_color);
        _render_api->clear();
    }

    ExampleLayer(Application * app) :
        Layer("Gameplay"),
        _app{ app }
    {
        _render_api = RenderAPI::create();
        _render_api->set_context(_app->window()->context());
    }

    ~ExampleLayer() {
        delete _render_api;
    }

private:
    Application *_app;
    RenderAPI *_render_api;

    float clear_color[4]{ 0.1f, 0.15f, 0.1f, 1.0f };
};
```

I am sorry to not have more to go on. The debug output from Visual Studio is silent on matters relating to DirectX (though it wasn't always - it helped me catch an error yesterday, so at least I know it works). I'm not sure what else I can do to gather evidence or hunt for clues, so here I am.

Thank you in advance to anyone who bothers to read this, let alone those noble souls who offer help. =)

Answer (score 0):

As one expects in this situation, it was a simple error. Specifically, I was never setting the `_output_size` member variable in the DX11 context.

```
void DX11Context::init() {
    create_device_resources();
    ::GetWindowRect(_window, &_output_size);
    create_window_dependent_resources();
}
```

The second line of this function solved the issue entirely. =)